# General formula for $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^pA^i$

Tags: summation

I was trying to sum series for fun and then I thought that since I can find the sum of polynomials and that of a geometric series then maybe I can find the sum of their product..I could find 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n iA^i
$$
Where $A$ is a constant easily but then when I tried higher powers for $i$ like $i^2$ $i^3$ $...$ I found it very difficult and I got curious if there is a formula like Faulhabeer's..and after a lot of tries I reached this formula which actually works
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^pA^i =\left (\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} j^p -(j-1)^p\right) \frac{A(A^n-1)}{A-1} +(n^p-(n-1)^p)A^n- \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}((k+1)^p-k^p) \frac{A(A^k-1)}{A-1}\right)
$$
But it's not practical so I want to know if there is a simpler and more practical way to find the sum

Comment: Hint: try integration and then taking the derivatives with respect to A.

Comment: Then I would end up with a series of power of $p-1$ and if $p=4$ for example.this isn't any easiear to sum.and what do you mean differentiate with respect to A? it's a constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just for your curiosity.*

There is a formula (the problem is that it still hides a summation !)
$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^p\,A^i =\text{Li}_{-p}(A)-A^{n+1}\, \Phi (A,-p,n+1)$$ where appear the polylogarithm function and  Lerch transcendent function.

Fo $p=4$ as in your comment, this would give the ugly
$$\frac{(A-1)^5}A S_n=\left((A-1)^4 n^4-4 (A-1)^3 n^3+6 (A-1)^2 (A+1) n^2-4 A (A (A+3)-3) n+A (A
   (A+11)+11)+4 n+1\right) A^n+(-A-1) (A (A+10)+1)$$

It would look better using $A=B+1$ which would make
$$\frac{B^5}{B+1} S_n=-B^3-14 B^2-36 B-24+$$ $$\left(B^4 n^4+B^3 \left(-4 n^3+6 n^2-4 n+1\right)+2 B^2 \left(6
   n^2-12 n+7\right)+B (36-24 n)+24\right) (B+1)^n$$

Comment: Hi Claude. I never saw this, nice! Then it gives a closed-form expression to the Faulhaber formulas .

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Hi Yves ! In fact, this is a problem I worked a loooong time ago and I never thought I would reuse it. Cheers.

Comment: Fortunately, formulas don't go out of fashion :-)

Comment: This is amazing..thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to attempt and give a recursive formula solution.

Let

$$
S_j(x,N)=\sum_{k=1}^N{k^j x^k} \ .
$$

Then it follows:

\begin{aligned}
S_j(x,N) &= \sum_{k=1}^N  x \frac{d}{dx} {k^{j-1} x^k} \\
 &=   x \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^N{k^{j-1} x^k} \\
 &= x \frac{d}{dx} S_{j-1}(x,N) \ .
\end{aligned}

We know that $S_0(x,N)=\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}$. So the general term becomes:

\begin{aligned}
S_j(x,N) &=\left(x \frac{d}{dx} \right)^j S_0(x,N)\\
 &= \left(x \frac{d}{dx} \right)^j \left(\frac{x^{N+1}-1}{x-1}\right) \ .
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=0}^n x^i=(x^{n+1}-1)(x-1)^{-1}.$$

Then

$$\sum_{i=0}^n ix^i=\frac d{dx} (x^{n+1}-1)(x-1)^{-1}=(n+1)x^n(x-1)^{-1}-(x^{n+1}-1)(x-1)^{-2}.$$

More generally, using the Leibniz formula,

$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^mx^i=\frac{d^m}{dx^m}(x^{n+1}-1)(x-1)^{-1}
\\=(x^{n+1}-1)(m-n+2)!(x-1)^{m-n+1}+
\\\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^k\binom mk\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-k+1)!}x^{n-k+1}(m-k+2)!(x-1)^{-(m-k+1)}
\\=(x^{n+1}-1)(m-n+2)!(x-1)^{m-n+1}+
\\x^{n-m}\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^k\binom mk\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-k+1)!}(m-k+2)!\left(\frac x{1-x}\right)^{m-k+1}.$$

As the derivative of $x^{n+1}$ cancels after order $m+1$, the summation is indeed up to $k=\min(m,n+1)$.

Comment: Computation errors not excluded. Double check.